# How can I configure Apigility to send HMAC-Authorization response headers?

Tags: http-headers, hmac, laminas-api-tools

I'm implementing an authorization in Apigility using Hmac. Basically I'm using the classe of this fella both for client and server (https://github.com/reinaldoborges/rb-sphinx-hmac-zf2-client).

Now I have this piece of code before sending a GET to my Api.

```
$hmac = new HMAC(
            new HMACv0(), 
            new PHPHash('sha256'), 
            new StaticKey('[PRE-SHARED KEY]'), 
            new DummyNonce()       
    );

    $hmac->setKeyId('certkey');
    $hmac->setNonceValue('certNonce');


    $uri = "http://apicert.local/certificados";
    $cliente = new HMACHttpClient($uri);
    $cliente->setMethod('GET');
    $cliente->setHmac($hmac);

    try {
        $cliente->send();

        /**
         * Resposta
         */
        echo "Request HMAC Header:", PHP_EOL; **I'm asking for a Reply using HMAC-Authorization type of header **
        echo '     ', HMACHttpClient::HEADER_NAME, ' = ', $cliente->getHeader(HMACHttpClient::HEADER_NAME), PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        /**
         * ERRO
         */
        echo "##### ERRO #####", PHP_EOL;
        echo $e->getCode(), ' : ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
        echo "##### ERRO #####", PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
    }
    $response = $cliente->getResponse();
    echo "Response Status Code: ", $response->getStatusCode(), PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
    echo "Response Headers: ";
    print_r($response->getHeaders()->toArray());
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo "Response Cookies:", PHP_EOL;
    $cookies = $response->getCookie();
    foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
        echo '     ', $cookie->toString(), PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo "Response Body:", PHP_EOL;
    echo $response->getBody();
    echo PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
```

And I'm receiving a 406 Status Code that refers that this kind of header is not acceptable. I tried to add in content negotion whitelist but there is not this option. How can I receive the authorization from the server then?

Request HMAC Header: HMAC-Authentication = 1:certkey:certNonce:f9c9edcda43df5c466e54449f31900a6f9387afa32168327a0873a69b023abef Response Status Code: 406 Response Headers: Array ( [Date] => Thu, 11 Aug 2016 23:55:33 GMT [Server] => Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) [Access-Control-Max-Age] => 1000 [Access-Control-Allow-Headers] => X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding [Access-Control-Allow-Methods] => POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => * [Content-Length] => 149 [Connection] => close [Content-Type] => application/problem+json ) Response Cookies: Response Body: {"type":"http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html","title":"Not Acceptable","status":406,"detail":"Cannot honor Accept type specified"}

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new Authorization type.
In the APigility ui there is a button in the top named Authorization.
Here you can add any authorization adapter you want. Even the hmac adapter if you want.

Personally i have used this to create a jwt adapter.

Now, this adapter should extend `ZF\MvcAuth\Authentication\AdapterInterface`.
I've also added this adapter to my service manager.